# PHP ODBC extract substrings from string to create variables

Tags: php, odbc, substring, substr

I am not even sure if this is possible.  I have google searched for this, but I am not finding exactly what I need.

Basically, I have a query that returns a string.  The string is long, and appears to have an * as a "separator".  It is still one single string.

What I need to do, is take the first two actual words and turn them into variables.

When the string is returned, it looks similar to this:

```
 ABCD*RANDOMNAME*VB259E*5301*26042014*4992*K*CMAU
```

As you can see, there is an * separating each portion.

I need to extract the first two parts, where it reads ABCD and RANDOMNAME.  Of course, the first 4 characters are also random but will always be 4 characters.  After the first * where it reads RANDOMNAME, this part may have more or less characters.  But I don't need anything after the second *.

I think I have to use the substr function, but I am not sure how to apply it in this case.

I retrieve the results like this:

```
 <?php
   voyage = $_POST['voyage'];
   $query = "SELECT blah blah blah FROM blah WHERE blah = '$voyage'";

   $result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);  // result is a long string as detailed above

   $first = ""; // first substring
   $second = "";  // second substring

  // both would go into this next variable

 $dateFile = $first . " - " . $second . " - " . $voyage . " - " . date('dmY'). ".txt";

 ?>
```

So as you can see, I need to extract the substrings to create a name for a text file.

The 2 substrings would go into the variables $first and $second.

I would appreciate any help.

PLEASE PLEASE PLEASE - I am still trying to master PHP and MYSQL.  My client is using an Oracle database, so I literally just started using PHP and ODBC commands.  Please forgive my ignorance regarding this matter.  If you have an answer that will help me, then by all means please assist.  If not, please move to the next question.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a SQL or PHP string manipulation question than anything else, and shouldn't be too difficult. You can either extract the string that exists in a column into PHP and do the manipulation there, or do it entirely in SQL and simply fetch from the separated columns.

Here's the SQL example:

```
select 
    left(
        'ABCD*RANDOMNAME*VB259E*5301*26042014*4992*K*CMAU', 
        locate('*', 'ABCD*RANDOMNAME*VB259E*5301*26042014*4992*K*CMAU') - 1) as first, 
    substring(
        'ABCD*RANDOMNAME*VB259E*5301*26042014*4992*K*CMAU', 
        locate('*', 'ABCD*RANDOMNAME*VB259E*5301*26042014*4992*K*CMAU'), 
        locate('*', 'ABCD*RANDOMNAME*VB259E*5301*26042014*4992*K*CMAU', locate('*', 'ABCD*RANDOMNAME*VB259E*5301*26042014*4992*K*CMAU') + 1) - locate('*', 'ABCD*RANDOMNAME*VB259E*5301*26042014*4992*K*CMAU')) as second
```

I've used a string literal here for your string that you're trying to extract, I assume in your SQL you would instead use a column reference. Note that this is using ODBC scalar functions, you may need to wrap each invocation of left/locate/substring in {fn ... } in some ODBC drivers. The SQL is fairly messy, but it works.

The second, and likely easier solution, is do the extraction in PHP itself:

```
$string = 'ABCD*RANDOMNAME*VB259E*5301*26042014*4992*K*CMAU';

$firstStarIndex = strpos($string, '*');
$first = substr($string, 0, $firstStarIndex);
$second = substr($string, $firstStarIndex + 1, strpos($string, '*', $firstStarIndex + 1) - $firstStarIndex - 1);
```

Note that error checking and validation is omitted for brevity.